# How to get Eclipse to work properly with Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle

I am trying out Eclipse (because of frustrations with apparent version incompatibilities when upgrading another IDE), but it is proving equally problematic. This is a perfectly clean Eclipse installation (windows installer, second variant option), so it's an ootb issue.

(Simplified, theoretically-reproducable version): I downloaded two copies of a basic Java 17 project from Spring Initializr with no dependencies; one as Gradle, one as Maven (tester & tester2 respectively). The Gradle build shows errors where there are none, per the screenshot.

[image: Eclipse with different builds of the same project, one errors]

Note that in the one class in the besic, clean SpringBoot application, it sees the package name, the class name, and even the definition of `String` as being errors. But the same code in the Maven version is fine.

There are further issues that appear to derive from this, but keeping it simple…

At some point during my testing, some message/error showed up that suggested it was building with Gradle 6.8.3, which I believe would be a problem as that version doesn't support Java 16+. Eclipse is configured to use 7.3.

How do I tell Eclipse to recognise a valid project, so it can be worked with?

Comment: There are different Eclipse IDE package with different JavaScript editors. Unfortunately, your question does not tell [how to reproduce this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you use [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) which exists for more than three years? Which documentation did you follow?

Comment: I downloaded the Windows Eclipse installer, ran it, selected the option that looked most appropriate – something about java and web; second on the list – and used that. From there, the easy way to recreate the issue is to download a basic empty Java 17 gradle project from Spring Initializr; it gives some of the same issues with not recognising the imports, not recognising the root application class…

Comment: All of the packages use Wild Web Developer for JavaScript/ECMAScript files.

Comment: Wild Web Developer is installed. I downlaoded the Maven equivalent empty Spring Initializr project and that doesn't give any errors. There was some mention in some error of it having built with Gradle 6.8.3, even though it was configured to build with 7.2; maybe the issue is there.

Comment: Instead of making assumptions, just tell how to reproduce your issue. Please edit your question and provide an example file with which your issue can be reproduced. Are you talking about a *.js file? With which editor did you open it?

Comment: My partial reproduction is a fresh Windows install of Eclipse – using the installer, second IDE variant option – and get a Spring Initializr project (Java 17) with no dependencis configured. Open that project and the imports fail. I don't know how you want me to give you more; yes, there's the more complex version whereby opening an exising project throws up other errors, including in *.js files, but as there's a basic problem with the cleanest project I can put in it, that's the best place to start.

Comment: Please show a [minimal(!) reproducible(!) example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) focusing of one issue only. You have to show some code (as text), tell with which editor to open it (show an screenshot when you cannot name the editor) and also tell what you expect instead.

Comment: Edited to focus on its behaviour with a simple Springboot project (and hoping that the same cause as all the other issues which I can't offer in any reproducible form as you won't have the same project to work with.)

Comment: Expand the node for "Project and External Dependencies". If the project can't find `java.lang.String`, a JRE is somehow missing from the Build Path.

Comment: In the first project the _JRE System Library_ node is missing in the _Project Explorer_. Without knowing what is in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the `build.gradle` file and the error message (shown in the _Problems_ view), it is hard to guess what's wrong here. It is also a bit wired that you do not use [https://spring.io/tools](https://spring.io/tools) for a Spring based project. The original title now seems to be unrelated. Take your time and learn the basics before making assumptions about the tools you use.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. I had no reason to know that Spring Tools even existed; why would I? (Now installed, makes no difference.) And "learning" about it means using it, or banging my head against it without meaningful guidance. (Anything I search for comes up with information on years-old versions that are no longer relevant.) Yes, _JRE System Library_ is missing. In the Libraries tab in _Project Explorer_, it is under Classpath with an error icon, and is marked as "(unbound)"; in the Maven version, it's under Modulepath. I didn't put any of those there; as I said, clean Initializr projects.

Comment: _"(unbound)"_ means here you have to configure a Java of the appropriate version in the preferences (_Window > Preferences_) in _Java > Installed JREs_.